# Error While creating SPSite instance with SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointfoundation2010, spsite

I'm getting the following error while trying to create a SPSite instance (not open it, just create it):

```
"The Web application at <URL> could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application."
```

I have SharePoint Foundation 2010 installed on x64 Windows 7 laptop and VS 2008. I've done a lot of searching the last couple of days and I've tried any suggestion there is:

- Setting user permissions to the database.
- Targeting the application for x64 CPU.
- Running my app with the sharepoint app pool account. Creating new app pool.
- Creating windows forms and console applications to run the code from there.
- Adding and removing the web application administrators.
- Checked the logs (nothing in there).
- Writing the URL in full, with machine name and with IP.

The funny thing is that the same code was working fine at one point and then just stopped. I cannot recall to have done anything special to damage it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,
Martin

Comment: can you paste the code block you are using that is causing this error?

Comment: Have you tried disabling ACLs and then again creating the SP Site instance

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question the sharepoint site had to be on the default port - 80. Publishing it on any other port and trying to access it by putting the port in the URL did not work. Strange but it worked.